# Computing arbitrary R function on dplyr remote table

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

In order to essentially compute some arbitrary R code on a database, a pretty common workflow I find myself in is something like this:

1) Query remote database to pull down the data into R.

2) Perform some manipulation in R, usually to generate features that can't be easily computed in the database.

3) Upload the data back to the database for future access.

Now, if the data isn't too big then this is pretty straightforward, and living in the tidyverse I'd do something like this:

```
ds <- tbl(con, "table") %>%
  collect() %>%
  mutate(complex_feature = ...)
copy_to(con, ds, "table_transformed", temporary = F)
```

Which is fine (although if there's a better way please let me know).

But the problem comes when I'm dealing with a dataset that won't fit in memory. I could take a split-apply-combine approach and write a loop that downloads chunks of the dataset, performs the manipulation, and appends them to a table in the database, but this doesn't seem very elegant.

I'm thinking there's a more general way to do it, maybe using some of the functional techniques in the tidyverse, but has anyone got any ideas?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You may consider spark and sparkR package.  It connects to a number of databases and performs such transformations through "user-defined functions" on small chunks of data.  However, it has quite a bit of learning curve, and serialization for udf-s is slow.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for the reply. That's a great suggestion, I've played around with Spark, mostly via the sparklyr package, but I've definitely found there to be a steep learning curve. Maybe I should just bite the bullet though...

Comment: If you want to go for spakrlyr, check if it now does udf-s.  It didn't for a while ago.

Comment: maybe I'm stating the obvious, but don't you ever use `dplyr` functions before calling `collect` ? depending on how complex is your complex features you might even be able to not load anything in R

Comment: Yeah, sorry if I wasn't clear but by "complex features" I meant the use of functions that the database doesn't have. So for example I'm using quite a few functions from the stringdist package that, at least as far as I'm aware, don't have MySQL equivalents (and since I don't own the database I have to use MySQL).